# Use value from select to set corresponding marker icons in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, style, select

I have a select that contains a list of cities my markers are in. I would like to display my L.icon markers according to the value currently selected, since the value selected will match the attribute value of same markers. I would basically like the size of the selected value/marker to be higher than the other markers.

I think I'm pretty close to the solution but I don't see where the problem is. I get an error about the "onEachFeature" not being a function in the console log, but nothing elese. My select list is empty (without this part of the code, it's full). All of my markers are here, but without their original style.

How can I do this?

```
// Init select value

var ville_select = "Lyon"

// Update the select value at each click

$('#monselect').change(function(){
  ville_select = $(this).val();
  console.log(ville_select)
})

// Function that will get the size value depending on the attribute value

function getSize(ville){
  if (ville_select == ville){
    return [20, 20]
  } else {
    return [10, 10]
  }
}

// Fetch the data and style it 

var getData = "https://" + config.cartoUsername + ".carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=" + sqlQuery;
function getGeoJSON() {
  $.getJSON(getData, function (data) {
    cartoData = L.geoJson(data, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlong) {
        var markerStyle = { 

// Use the getSize() function here to get the size value according to the attribute

            iconSize: getSize(feature.properties.ville),
            iconUrl: './images/star.png'
        };

        return L.icon(latlong, markerStyle);
    },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('' + feature.properties.description + '<br>Proposé par ' + feature.properties.name + '<br>Dans la ville de ' + feature.properties.ville);
      }

    }).addTo(map)
//
```

Comment: Is property `feature.properties.ville` unique for features? If not, do features have some other unique property?

Comment: No, it isn't, some features have the same property hence why I'm trying to display them according to this property. On the other hand ```Feature.properties.description``` is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unluckily GeoJSON layer in Leaflet has style function only for lines and polygons, but not for points/markers. This means that to change style of desired points/markers, one has either iterate through all the layers in GeoJSON group layer to find the right ones, or have some method to directly access them.

One way to directly access them is through their layer id and `.getLayer(layerId)` method. For this to work there must be some link established between desired feature property and corresponding marker layer. This can be done initially by looping through all the features/markers and constructing object (let's say it's `propertyToLayerId`) where key is property value and values for that key are corresponding marker layer ids (if this sounds vague/complicated, see code below).

Now, when icons have to be changed for features with desired property value, corresponding marker layer ids are retrieved from `propertyToLayerId` and icons set for those markers.

So code could then look something like this:

```
var propertyToLayerId = {};  
var cartoData;

var iconDefault = L.icon({
  iconUrl: './images/star.png',
  iconSize: [10, 10]
});
var iconSelected = L.icon({
  iconUrl: './images/star.png',
  iconSize: [20, 20]
});

function setFeaturesIcon(propertyValue, icon) {
  var layerId = propertyToLayerId[propertyValue];
  for (var i = 0; i < layerId.length; i++) {
    var marker = cartoData.getLayer(layerId[i]);
    marker.setIcon(icon);
  }
}

var ville_select = null;
function setSelectedFeatureIcon(propertyValue) {
  if (propertyValue == ville_select) return;
  
  if (ville_select) {
    setFeaturesIcon(ville_select, iconDefault);
    ville_select = null;
  }
  if (propertyValue) {
    setFeaturesIcon(propertyValue, iconSelected);
    ville_select = propertyValue;
  }
}

var getData = "https://" + config.cartoUsername + ".carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=" + sqlQuery;

function getGeoJSON() {
  $.getJSON(getData, function (data) {
    cartoData = L.geoJson(data, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlong) {
        var marker = L.marker(latlong, {icon: iconDefault});
        return marker;
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('' + feature.properties.description + '<br>Proposé par ' + feature.properties.name + '<br>Dans la ville de ' + feature.properties.ville);
      }
    }).addTo(map);
    cartoData.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      var owner = layer.feature.properties.ville;
      var layerId = cartoData.getLayerId(layer);
      if (propertyToLayerId[owner])
        propertyToLayerId[owner].push(layerId);
      else {
        propertyToLayerId[owner] = [layerId];
      }
    });
    setSelectedFeatureIcon('Lyon');
    $('#monselect').change(function(){
      setSelectedFeatureIcon($(this).val());
      console.log(ville_select)
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: You've forgotten about `pointToLayer`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez But it's executed only at the time of adding data to the layer. How could it be used to dynamically change marker icon sizes later?

Comment: By iterating through all members of the geojson group, using `eachLayer`.

Comment: But that would mean creating new markers, not modifying existing ones. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't think OP wants/needs to modify markers, just to create them in two different sizes - a `pointToLayer` job.

Comment: I don't think so, according to `$('#monselect').change( ...` this seems dynamic stuff.